# Can't connect to WPA2 Enterprise network with fresh Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and I have successfully connected to my WiFi at home. I can't connect to my WiFi at work, however. After googling for solutions I found that a common solution is to remove a line from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/[SSID name]` which relates to certificates... I don't have this line in my file though and I'm not sure how to solve it.

This is what my `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/e-device` file looks like:

```
[connection]
id=e-device
uuid=6c673ee3-3438-445b-bff1-45889d59b27e
type=wifi
permissions=user:x:;
secondaries=

[wifi]
mac-address=34:02:86:42:81:FA
mac-address-blacklist=
mac-address-randomization=0
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=
ssid=e-device

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
group=
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
pairwise=
proto=

[802-1x]
altsubject-matches=
eap=peap;
identity=[my_username_here]
password=[my_password_here]
phase2-altsubject-matches=
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

I've also learned that editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` may solve the issue. This is what mine looks like.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Any idea what I can do to fix the issue?

Comment: What kind of authentication does the wireless network at your work have? I'm guessing it's some variant of WPA2 enterprise. Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) after a (failed) connection attempt and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.