# Ubuntu 16.04: No internet with WPA & WPA2 Enterprise (using Certificate)

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, acer

First time asking a question!

I am trying to connect to my univeristy's wifi with my new Acer Aspire F15 laptop, and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit. I have previously connected to my wifi at home with no problem, and I can connect to the internet through my phone hotspot. The problem is ***not*** that I cannot connect to the router - it lets me connect fine. Once I am connected, however, I am unable to connect to the internet. I have also checked with IT services, and I have supposedly set all the settings correctly (including the use of a certificate - see attachment for settings). Using these same settings with an older Acer laptop running the same distro of Ubuntu worked just fine.

This problem is also not consistent. I went into my univeristy's IT help desk, deleted the connection, and reconnected and was able to have internet access while in their building. After walking back to my office, however, I no longer had internet access, and deleting and reconnecting didn't fix the problem. I've asked the IT desk if they have any insight, but they seem to be out of their depth since they almost exclusively work with Windows and Mac.

I've tried different solutions offered on this website, including setting `auth-alg=open` within the `[wifi-security]` section of the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wpa.mcgill.ca` file with no luck. [This person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819956/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-network-with-fresh-ubuntu-16-04) seems to have similar problem as me, without a solution.

I've included a screenshot showing my connection settings (with my username and password removed just for the picture). I've also included the relevant outputs from some commands I've heard of to save you some time (with details I thought should be removed, replaced with the # symbol). Let me know if you need any other output!

Any help would be much appreciated! I'd rather not keep using my cell data...

```
$ sudo lspci -vnn
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:08a6]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=8/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:108f]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a1204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Qualcomm Atheros
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 31
   serial: 94:e9:79:e4:91:b3
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-70-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=###.###.###.## latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:131 memory:a1000000-a11fffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
   logical name: enp3s0f1
   version: 12
   serial: a8:1e:84:0b:05:2b
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:127 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff

$ iwconfig
enp3s0f1  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"wpa.mcgill.ca"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: ##:##:##:##:##:##   
      Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:20   Missed beacon:0

$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wpa.mcgill.ca 
[connection]
id=wpa.mcgill.ca
uuid=##########################
type=wifi
permissions=user:####:;
secondaries=
timestamp=#######

[wifi]
mac-address=##:##:##:##:##:##
mac-address-blacklist=
mac-address-randomization=0
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=##:##:##:##:##:##;##:##:##:##:##:##;
ssid=wpa.mcgill.ca

[wifi-security]
group=
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
pairwise=
proto=

[802-1x]
altsubject-matches=
ca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
eap=peap;
identity=########@mail.mcgill.ca
password=#######
phase2-altsubject-matches=
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Screenshot showing parameters used to connect to Wifi:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Upgrading from the `4.4.0-72-generic` kernel to the `4.8.0-46-generic` kernel has not resolved my problems... Still no solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for taking the time to write a high-quality question! (As regular users, it's quite annoying always having to be fixing terrible grammar and spelling.) Also, I've edited your question to have the image embedded in the post itself :)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how to embed it. I see how now though!

Comment: Well, actually you have to have at least 10 reputation points for the system to let you embed it. Otherwise, it will only let you put a link.

Comment: This problem resolved itself for me FYI - no idea what fixed it in the end: whether it was a kernel update or if it was upgraded hardware or something in my building. Either way, no issues now.

Comment: Ok, voting to close as "a problem that seemingly went away on its own"